# Detect mouse click on object with no script attached

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, input

I'm creating a 2D project which does not have a character. So I created an empty game object and attached a script to it. In the script, I have declared other objects which are in the scene like this:

```
public GameObject obj1,obj2,obj3;
```

How can I know if obj1 or obj2 or obj3 was clicked? Is raycasting the only solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use [raycasting](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to detect the objects in your scene. You don't need to attach a custom script to the game objects you want to detect, but you do need to attach colliders to them.

In the update method of your script, attached to the otherwise empty object, you can check for when the mouse button is pressed. Then, cast a ray into the scene from the camera, through the mouse. Something like the following:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Debug.Log("Pressed left click, casting ray.");
        CastRay();
    }
}

void CastRay() {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) {
        Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin, hit.point);
        Debug.Log("Hit object: " + hit.collider.gameobject.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The first Debug line is printed to console. Then i get this: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object). But the last Debug line is not shown.

Comment: Also, the raycast is firing when i click my GUI buttons too. Is that a problem?

Comment: Read the documentation on raycasting. You need to add colliders to the objects you want to be detected with the ray. Yes, the ray will be cast any time you press the mouse button, that includes when pressing for GUI items, you'll need to detect separately when clicking a GUI item and not allow the raycast in those situations. That's an entirely different question though and not suitable to be addressed in the comments of this answer.

Comment: Yes I added BoxCollider2D to the object. Object name is not shown in the console.

Comment: If it's a 2D collider, you need the [2D raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I was able to alter it for 2D collider :)

Answer (score 5):

I modified the script and now it works. First, I remove:

```
public GameObject obj1, obj2, obj3; // Although this shouldn't affect the script.
```

The updated script is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickTest : MonoBehaviour {
    // public GameObject red, red2, yellow, yellow2, MainCamera;
    // Use this for initialization

    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Debug.Log("Pressed left click, casting ray.");
            CastRay();
        }       
    }

    void CastRay() {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);
        if (hit) {
            Debug.Log (hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Still Believe that part of this question was not answered. The part

> Is raycasting the only solution?

Well its not the only solution there is also:

```
void OnMouseDown(){
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Attach that script to the target object i.e. the one that wants to register the mouse clicks.

Comment: Actually can't use OnMouseDown() as I have many objects and attaching the script to each of them is not feasible

Comment: Oh Ok... that would be overkill. BUt i wanted to prove that raycasting is not the ONLY solution as had been asked. Also you could do a foreach on the gameObjects and add the script using gameObject.AddComponent<MyScript>()

Comment: Yes adding component by having an array is a possibility. But there would be more issues. For example, I don't just want to know if the object was clicked. I want to do something with that information. For example, change the clicked objects color. Considering all the things, raycasting remained the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up an edge collider on the objects you can use:

```
void Update()
{
    //this detects the mouse position
    Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    //this check to see if the mouse is over the collider documentation below
    if (this.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>().ClosestPoint(mousePos) == mousePos)
    {
         print("mouse is hovering over object");
         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
         {
             print("mouse clicked on object");
         }
    }
 }
```

For more information, refer to the [documentation for `Collider.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html).