# How to avoid mouse click over the trigger object?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I'm detecting mouse clicks if the click is happening over the collider but I don't want to fire mouse clicks if it is on the trigger object. How to I do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you detecting which object was clicked?

Comment: I'm using OnTriggerStay2D() method and some boolean variables to detect the mouse click...                                                                                                                         void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D col)
 {
  if (gameObject.name == "elephant" && col.gameObject.name == "elephant 1") {
   canShow = true;
   if (canClick) {
    Show (col.gameObject);
    ObjectActivate ("book1");
   }

  }            canClick will become true if the object on the trigger and the mouse is clicked. But i don't want user to click on the trigger object.

Comment: Where is this Collision detection script attached?

Comment: Gameobject that i am picking. Here it is 'elephant'.

Comment: Then, that script is completely wrong. It does not detect mouse clicks. It detects if  elephant collided with elephant1

Comment: Yes that is what i am doing if elephant collid with elephant1 then canShow variable will become true and if the canShow is true then it waiting for mouse click if the mouse is clicked on the object then canClick will become true then i'l do some task.

Comment: Ok. How are you detecting Mouse clicks?

Answer (score 0):

[How to detect clicks on object?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82928/2d-detect-mouse-click-on-object-with-no-script-attached/82947#82947) . This is a question I had asked.
The proper way to detect mouse clicks is to use RayCasting, RayCast2D for 2D. While Raycasting, you can specify layermask, which let's you ignore objects which you want to ignore.

The second answer on the aforementioned question provides a solution for 2D.

Comment: Yeah it's good but how do i detect collision when the object collid with another object. Because here we can't use default OnTriggerXXX() method....

Comment: Your question is not clear. In your post, you asked : "I'm detecting the mouse clicks" . This answers how to detect mouse clicks. If you want to know how to detect collision between two objects, post a new question.